# Nodes with case-insensitive content using XOM

Tags: xpath, xom

I want to query nodes from a XOM document which contains certain value but case insensitive. Something like this:

```
doc.query('/root/book[contains(.,"case-insentive-string")]')
```

But it *contains* is case sensitive.

1. I tried to use regexes, but it is
   only XPATH2.0 and XOM does not seem
   to support it.
2. I tried
   `contains(translate(."ABCEDF...","abcdef..."),"case-insentive-string")]'`
   failed too.
3. I tried to match
   subnodes and read parent attributes
   using getParent, but there is no
   method to read parents attributes.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete sollution, explanation and an example. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XOM, then you can use Saxon to run XPath or XQuery against it. That gives you the ability to use the greatly increased function library in XPath 2.0, which includes functions lower-case() and upper-case(), and also the ability (though in a somewhat product-specific way) to choose your own collations for use with functions such as contains() - which means you can do matching that ignores accents as well as case, for example.

Comment: I do use Saxon 8 which also has regexes, maybe something is wrong with my config. I will check again.

Comment: Indeed I get the following error : `Caused by: org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: No Such Function lower-case`. How do u get saxon called ???

Answer (score 2):

> 2.I tried contains(translate(."ABCEDF...","abcdef..."),"case-insentive-string")]'
>   failed too.

**The proper way to write this is**:

```
/root/book[contains(translate(., $vUpper, $vLower),
                    translate($vCaseInsentiveString, $vUpper, $vLower)
                    )
          ]
```

where `$vUpper` and `$vLower` are defined as (should be substituted by) the strings:

```
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

and

```
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

and `$vCaseInsentiveString` is defined as (should be substituted by) the specific case-insensitive string.

**For example, given the following XML document**:

```
<authors>
  <author>
    <name>Victor Hugo &amp; Co.</name>
    <nationality>French</nationality>
  </author>
  <author period="classical" category="children">
    <name>J.K.Rollings</name>
    <nationality>British</nationality>
  </author>
  <author period="classical">
    <name>Sophocles</name>
    <nationality>Greek</nationality>
  </author>
  <author>
    <name>Leo Tolstoy</name>
    <nationality>Russian</nationality>
  </author>
  <author>
    <name>Alexander Pushkin</name>
    <nationality>Russian</nationality>
  </author>
  <author period="classical">
    <name>Plato</name>
    <nationality>Greek</nationality>
  </author>
</authors>
```

**the following XPath expression** (substitute the variables by the corresponding strings):

```
   /*/author/name
              [contains(translate(., $vUpper, $vLower),
                        translate('lEo', $vUpper, $vLower)
                        )
              ]
```

**selects this element**:

```
<name>Leo Tolstoy</name>
```

**Explanation**: *Both* arguments of the `contains()` function are converted to lower-case, and then the comparison is performed.